# Can I force a shared C++ library to fail to build if a class isn't fully implemented?

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, cmake, linker

I have C++ plugins:

```
class PluginBase
{
    public:

        virtual void foo () = 0;
        virtual void bar () = 0;
};

extern "C" PluginBase * new_instance ();
```

This is implemented as a shared library

```
class PluginImplementation : public PluginBase
{
    void foo () override;
    void bar () override;
}

void PluginImplementation::foo () {}

// void PluginImplementation::bar () {}   // NOTE: MISSING

extern "C" PluginBase * new_instance ()
{
    return new PluginImplementation ();
}
```

This is built with `CMake` using `gcc`:

```
ADD_LIBRARY (plugin_implementation SHARED PluginImplementation.cpp)
```

This builds `libplugin_implementation.so` even though `PluginImplementation::bar` is not implemented.

I get that the missing symbol might be defined elsewhere in the program at runtime, so the linker permits it to be missing from a dynamic library.

I don't want that.

Is there a way to make the `.so` fail to build unless all *class* members are defined?

Comment: The `--no-undefined` GNU ld link flag might do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your target is modern ELF and you do not expect any direct references to this class by its name or other symbols, you can set the visibility to hidden:

```
class __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))
PluginImplementation : public PluginBase
```

The linker will then attempt to resolve the symbols for the functions implementing the virtual methods locally (within the shared object), and this will result in a hard linker error (wrapped for readability):

```
plugin.o:(.data.rel.ro.local._ZTV20PluginImplementation
  [_ZTV20PluginImplementation]+0x18):
  undefined reference to `PluginImplementation::bar()'
/usr/bin/ld: plugin.so: hidden symbol `_ZN20PluginImplementation3barEv'
  isn't defined
```

Even if you leave out the member function that controls the emission of the vtable (so that the shared object does not contain the vtable with its function pointers), the `new_instance` function calls a constructor which has to store the vtable pointer, and in the case of hidden visibility, that will produce an undefined symbol error, too.

Answer (score 2):

I would think you would have to create a test or some other piece of code that has a `main`, links to the shared library, and tries to instantiate the class in question. That seems like it would be a good idea anyway because you should be unit testing.

Comment: Yes for the unit test, which you should have been doing anyways.

Comment: One probably need --no-undefined, not --no-allow-shlib-undefined.

Comment: @n.m. - I tested that too. I gave the verbose option to the compiler and used `-Wl` to pass the flag and made sure it really did show up on the linker command line. No dice.